# SharePoint List not updating via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, powershell-ise

I'm currently trying to update a SharePoint List using lists.asmx. I can't use CSOM unfortunately, as this is going to be passed off as a batch file to non-technical people. I've got it working when adding new items to a list, but if I modify my code to update items in a list, none of the items are updated.

The code is as follows:

```
# Connect to web service
$uri = "http://teams.COMPANY.intranet/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -Namespace SpWs  -UseDefaultCredential # -credential $credential
$service.url = "http://home.COMPANY.intranet/sites/Sharepoint/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument            
$listName = "MapDetails"  
$viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")
$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")          

# Get name attribute values (guids) for list and view            
$ndlistview = $service.getlistandview($listname, "")            
$strlistid = $ndlistview.childnodes.item(0).name            
$strviewid = $ndlistview.childnodes.item(1).name            


# Create an xmldocument object and construct a batch element and its attributes.   

$xmldoc = new-object system.xml.xmldocument             

# note that an empty viewname parameter causes the method to use the default view               
$batchelement = $xmldoc.createelement("Batch")            
$batchelement.setattribute("onerror", "continue")            
$batchelement.setattribute("listversion", "1")            
$batchelement.setattribute("viewname", $strviewid)            

$id = 1                               
$xml = ""            

# The row to be modified            
$rowId = 0

$Files=GET-CHILDITEM '\\Client.COMPANY.com\Homeshare\HOME0029\USER\My Documents\WebTrends Global Adoption\Output\*.txt' | Sort-Object 

Foreach ($File in $Files) {

    $fullName = $File.BaseName
    $content = Get-Content $File

    $xml = "<Method ID='$id' Cmd='Update'>" +

  "<Field Name='ID'>$rowId</Field>" +

  "<Field Name='Title'>$fullName</Field>" +

  "<Field Name='LocationDetails'><![CDATA[$content]]></Field></Method>"

    # Set the xml content                    
    $batchelement.innerxml = $xml            

    $ndreturn = $null  

    $ndreturn = $service.updatelistitems($listname, $batchelement)

    $rowId++
}
```

I've scoured the web for a solution to this, but can't seem to find anybody with the same problem. Maybe I'm just being stupid. Feel free to point me in the right direction if this problem has been posted before.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there's no `***Update***` cmd...

Comment: My bad, the actual code reads 'Update', I put those around it to highlight the area, forgetting that it doesn't work in code blocks.